# How to make Docker bash completion work for container/image names for users other than root?

Tags: bash, docker, bash-completion

I downloaded the Docker bash completion script from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/cli/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker) to `/etc/bash_completion.d/docker`. The script works fine when I'm logged in as the root user. If I'm logged in as a non-root user, it works mostly fine except when I try to auto-complete image and container names. I'm trying to find a way to make this completion work without having to switch to the root user, mainly because that would be inconvenient in my workflow. Since my user is in the sudo group, is there a way to make the completion script utilize sudo as well?

Comment: `Since my user is in the sudo group,` Why not just add your user to the docker group? Does your user has appropriate permissions?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, that resolved the issue. Would you please post it as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KamilCuk stated- add your user to the `docker` group.

> `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`